# Why a pointer needs to be returned when the return type is actually error?

Tags: pointers, error-handling, go

I am reading the article [Error handling and Go](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go), and don't quite understand why a pointer (`&errorString{text}`) has to be returned when the return type is actually `error`?

My understanding is `error` is an interface, and `errorString` implements the interface, therefore, return `errorString` is also okay (but it is not the case).

```
// New returns an error that formats as the given text.
func New(text string) error {
    return &errorString{text}
}
```

errorString implementation

```
// errorString is a trivial implementation of error.
type errorString struct {
    s string
}

func (e *errorString) Error() string {
    return e.s
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `error` interface for `errorString` is implemented for a pointer (`func (e *errorString) Error()`), if it was implemented like below you would return the value directly:

```
func (e errorString) Error() string {
    return e.s
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Arjan. It works like what you said.  One thing I noticed is that if it were implemented as what you said, both return directly or return pointer work, do you know why?

Comment: It's how method sets for types are defined: http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

Comment: *T type can call methods with receiver defined both as *T or T